# How to transfer data from Android device to PC that runs on Windows via USB

Tags: usb-flash-drive, android, kindle

I am using Kindle Fire which runs on Android and need to transfer data from Android to my PC via USB. 
I have been using SnapPea for 9 months and it worked flawlessly.
Today, when I really need to download these files urgently, it doesn't work...
The thing is that, I can install apps via Snappea but in the past whenever I connected Kindle Fire via Snappea I was able to also see the device among my harddisks in Windows as if it was an USB flash drive, so I could download and upload data from PC to Kindle Fire and vice versa...

Do you know any other software or a solution how to do it?
I believe that if the software is for Android devices, it will work on Kindle Fire also since it's running on Android 2.3 (customized: 6.3.2_user_4110520).

I have been googling the solution for like 2 hours now but didn't find any software that can do it...

Comment: Is it plugged in?  Does it work when plugged into another computer?  Do other devices work in that USB port? Does it show up in the Device Manager, or under Devices? (assuming Windows)

Answer (score 2):

So, I noticed that in the bottom of Snappea there is an option to backup files from Kindle... I clicked on button "SD card" and it created some virtual FTP server:

```
ftp ://127.0.0.1:18871/sdcard/
```

From there I could download as well as upload files without a problem ...

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck in the future, and have WiFi access, I can vouch for [Wifi File Transfer Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smarterdroid.wififiletransferpro&hl=en). Great little app, easy to use UI.